# Inheriting from a referenced project in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I have a solution for a ASP.NET MVC application comprising (for now) 3 projects: the actual MVC application (P1), a modeling project (P2) and a base class library to hold the classes generated by my class diagram (P3).
I want to use these classes as a base for my models by inheriting from them.
From P1 I have already referenced P2 but, when creating a new class (be it a model or not) the  P2 namespace won't appear in intellisense! Not even in the "using" statement. What I would like to do, for instance:
public class Consultant : P3.Consultant
{
}
This doesn't seem to work, in spite of having a reference to P3.
Does anyone  have any idea why I'm having this issue. I'm used to doing this kind of separation on many other Windows applications; this is the first time I'm having this issue (it's also my first MVC app).
Thanks a lot.

Regards,

Antonio.

Comment: Which project are you trying to create the new class "Consultant" in?  P1 or P2?  I see the base class is in P3, but it is not clear where you're trying to create the new class.

If you're trying to inherit from P3.Consultant in P1, then you need to reference P3 in P1.  If you're trying to inherit from P3.Consultant in P2, then you need to reference P3 in P2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The MVC Web app is P1. P3 is where the UML generated base classes are. What I need to do is create a new class in P1 which inherits from a base class in P3.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do then, is to reference P3 from P1.  Then you can do this:

In P3:

```
namespace P3
{
    public class ClassInP3
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

In P1:

```
namespace P1.Models
{
    public class ClassInP1 : P3.ClassInP3
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I mistankenly wrote "From P1 I have already referenced P2" when I meant P3. That reference already exists, I just can't seem to use the classes on P3 namespace, neither with the using keyword or in the class definition.

Comment: Have you verified that the P3 class(es) are public?